# What is the relation between the algebraic dimensions of a vector space and its dual?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an (infinite dimensional) vector space over the field $\mathbb F (=\mathbb R$ or$ \mathbb C$). If $\alpha$ is the dimension of $V$, for some cardinal number $\alpha$, I want to know, what is the dimension of $V^*$, the algebraic dual of $V$?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was [reposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297845) a few minutes later, and correctly answered over there.

Answer (score -1):

$V^*$ is the linear space of all linear maps $r:V\to\mathbb{F}$. That this is indeed a linear space is easy to check. It is an elementary result that the dimensions of $V$ and $V^*$ are equal. To see this, try come up with a basis of $V^*$.

Comment: It is known that $dim V < dim V^*$ when $V$ is an infinite dimensional.