# The relation between the algebraic dimensions of a vector space and its dual

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an (infinite dimensional) vector space over the field $\mathbb F (=\mathbb R$ or$ \mathbb C$). If $\alpha$ is the dimension of $V$, for some cardinal number $\alpha$, I want to know, what is the dimension of $V^*$, the algebraic dual of $V$?
It is known that $dim V < dim V^*$ when V is an infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: There are interesting things on this very similar MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13322/slick-proof-a-vector-space-has-the-same-dimension-as-its-dual-if-and-only-if-i/13372#13372

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $\dim_{\mathbb F} V = d$ is infinite, we have
$$\dim_{\mathbb F} V^* = |\mathbb F|^d.$$ This theorem is attributed to Paul Erdős and Irving Kaplansky by Jacobson in *Lectures in Abstract Algebra II, Linear Algebra* (chapter IX.5, theorem 2, p.247).

Because of Cantor's theorem, you have $|\mathbb F|^d > d$, so you indeed have $\dim V^* > \dim V$ as soon as $V$ is infinite-dimensional.